DirectX 12 texture binding causes memcpy error
I have tried long and hard to solve this. So... I am contacting all of you guys! The issue is that each frame, I try and bind my texture:
Texture.hpp
class Texture : public Component
{
public:

    void Bind()
    {
        auto commandList = Renderer::GetInstance()->GetCommandList();

        UpdateSubresources(commandList.Get(), texture.Get(), textureUploadHeap.Get(), 0, 0, 1, &subresourceData);

        CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER barrier = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(texture.Get(), D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PIXEL_SHADER_RESOURCE);
        commandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &barrier);
    }

    void CleanUp() override
    {
        texture.Reset();
        textureUploadHeap.Reset();
    }

    ComPtr<ID3D12Resource> GetRaw()
    {
        return texture;
    }

    String GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    static Shared<Texture> Create(const String& name, const String& localPath, const String& domain = Settings::GetInstance()->Get<String>("defaultDomain"))
    {
        Shared<Texture> out = std::make_shared<Texture>();

        out->name = name;
        out->localPath = localPath;
        out->path = "Assets/" + domain + "/" + localPath;
        out->Generate();

        return out;
    }

private:

    void Generate()
    {
        ComPtr<IWICImagingFactory> factory;
        ComPtr<IWICBitmapDecoder> decoder;
        ComPtr<IWICBitmapFrameDecode> frame;
        ComPtr<IWICFormatConverter> converter;

        HRESULT result = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINITBASE_MULTITHREADED);

        if (FAILED(result))
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize COM library.");

        result = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory));

        if (FAILED(result))
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create WIC Imaging Factory.");

        result = factory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(WString(path.begin(), path.end()).c_str(), nullptr, GENERIC_READ, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, &decoder);

        if (FAILED(result))
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to load image.");

        result = decoder->GetFrame(0, &frame);

        if (FAILED(result))
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to get image frame.");

        result = factory->CreateFormatConverter(&converter);

        if (FAILED(result))
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create WIC format converter.");

        result = converter->Initialize(frame.Get(), GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppRGBA, WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, nullptr, 0.0, WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom);

        if (FAILED(result))
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize WIC format converter.");

        UINT width, height;

        result = converter->GetSize(&width, &height);

        if (FAILED(result))
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to get image dimensions.");

        Vector<unsigned char> imageData(width * height * 4);

        result = converter->CopyPixels(nullptr, width * 4, static_cast<UINT>(imageData.size()), imageData.data());

        if (FAILED(result))
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to copy image pixels.");

        auto device = Renderer::GetInstance()->GetDevice();

        D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC textureDescription = {};

        textureDescription.MipLevels = 1;
        textureDescription.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
        textureDescription.Width = width;
        textureDescription.Height = height;
        textureDescription.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_NONE;
        textureDescription.DepthOrArraySize = 1;
        textureDescription.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        textureDescription.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
        textureDescription.Dimension = D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;

        CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES heapProperties(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT);

        result = device->CreateCommittedResource(&heapProperties, D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE, &textureDescription, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&texture));

        if (FAILED(result))
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create texture resource.");

        const UINT64 uploadBufferSize = GetRequiredIntermediateSize(texture.Get(), 0, 1);

        CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES uploadHeapProperties(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD);
        CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC bufferDescription = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(uploadBufferSize);

        result = device->CreateCommittedResource(&uploadHeapProperties, D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE, &bufferDescription, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&textureUploadHeap));

        if (FAILED(result))
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create texture upload heap.");

        D3D12_SUBRESOURCE_DATA textureData = {};

        textureData.pData = imageData.data();
        textureData.RowPitch = static_cast<LONG_PTR>(width) * 4;
        textureData.SlicePitch = textureData.RowPitch * height;

        subresourceData = textureData;
    }

    String name;
    String localPath;
    String path;

    ComPtr<ID3D12Resource> texture;
    ComPtr<ID3D12Resource> textureUploadHeap;

    D3D12_SUBRESOURCE_DATA subresourceData = {};
};

Texture#Bind() is called once per frame, before the shader is bound.
Texture#Create() is called before the mesh is even created, and is called once at the start of the program. It is not called for each mesh created (that would be very inefficient!)
Just to help you understand, here is my shader class:
Shader.hpp
class Shader : public Component
{
public:

    void Bind()
    {
        auto commandList = Renderer::GetInstance()->GetCommandList();

        if (rootSignature)
            commandList->SetGraphicsRootSignature(rootSignature.Get());

        if (pipelineState)
            commandList->SetPipelineState(pipelineState.Get());

        ID3D12DescriptorHeap* descriptorHeaps[] = { constantBufferViewShaderResourceViewUnorderedAccessViewHeap.Get(), samplerHeap.Get() };
        commandList->SetDescriptorHeaps(_countof(descriptorHeaps), descriptorHeaps);

        if (!constantBuffers.empty() && !constantBufferDatas.empty())
            commandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(0, constantBufferViewShaderResourceViewUnorderedAccessViewHeap->GetGPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());

        if (!textures.empty())
            commandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(1, samplerHeap->GetGPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());
    }

    void CreateConstantBuffer(UINT bufferSize, UINT bufferIndex)
    {
        if (bufferIndex >= constantBuffers.size())
            constantBuffers.resize(static_cast<std::vector<ComPtr<ID3D12Resource>, std::allocator<ComPtr<ID3D12Resource>>>::size_type>(bufferIndex) + 1);

        CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES heapProps(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD);
        CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC bufferDescription = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(bufferSize);

        HRESULT result = Renderer::GetInstance()->GetDevice()->CreateCommittedResource(&heapProps, D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE, &bufferDescription, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&constantBuffers[bufferIndex]));

        if (FAILED(result))
            Logger_ThrowError("D3D12", "Failed to create constant buffer", true);

        constantBuffers[bufferIndex]->Map(0, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&constantBufferDatas[bufferIndex]));

        D3D12_CONSTANT_BUFFER_VIEW_DESC constantBufferViewDecription = {};

        constantBufferViewDecription.BufferLocation = constantBuffers[bufferIndex]->GetGPUVirtualAddress();
        constantBufferViewDecription.SizeInBytes = (bufferSize + 255) & ~255;

        CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE constantBufferViewHandle(constantBufferViewShaderResourceViewUnorderedAccessViewHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart(), bufferIndex, constantBufferViewShaderResourceViewUnorderedAccessViewDescriptorSize);
        Renderer::GetInstance()->GetDevice()->CreateConstantBufferView(&constantBufferViewDecription, constantBufferViewHandle);
    }

    void UpdateConstantBuffer(const void* data, Size dataSize, UINT bufferIndex)
    {
        memcpy(constantBufferDatas[bufferIndex], data, dataSize);
    }

    void CreateTexture(ComPtr<ID3D12Resource> resource, UINT textureIndex)
    {
        if (textureIndex >= textures.size())
            textures.resize(static_cast<std::vector<ComPtr<ID3D12Resource>, std::allocator<ComPtr<ID3D12Resource>>>::size_type>(textureIndex) + 1);

        textures[textureIndex] = resource;

        D3D12_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shaderResourceViewDescription = {};

        shaderResourceViewDescription.Shader4ComponentMapping = D3D12_DEFAULT_SHADER_4_COMPONENT_MAPPING;
        shaderResourceViewDescription.Format = resource->GetDesc().Format;
        shaderResourceViewDescription.ViewDimension = D3D12_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
        shaderResourceViewDescription.Texture2D.MipLevels = resource->GetDesc().MipLevels;

        CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE shaderResourceViewHandle(constantBufferViewShaderResourceViewUnorderedAccessViewHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart(), textureIndex + maxConstantBuffers, constantBufferViewShaderResourceViewUnorderedAccessViewDescriptorSize);
        Renderer::GetInstance()->GetDevice()->CreateShaderResourceView(resource.Get(), &shaderResourceViewDescription, shaderResourceViewHandle);
    }

    void CreateSampler(UINT samplerIndex)
    {
        if (samplerIndex >= samplers.size())
            samplers.resize(static_cast<std::vector<ComPtr<ID3D12Resource>, std::allocator<ComPtr<ID3D12Resource>>>::size_type>(samplerIndex) + 1);

        D3D12_SAMPLER_DESC samplerDescription = {};

        samplerDescription.Filter = D3D12_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
        samplerDescription.AddressU = D3D12_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE_WRAP;
        samplerDescription.AddressV = D3D12_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE_WRAP;
        samplerDescription.AddressW = D3D12_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE_WRAP;
        samplerDescription.MinLOD = 0;
        samplerDescription.MaxLOD = D3D12_FLOAT32_MAX;
        samplerDescription.MipLODBias = 0.0f;
        samplerDescription.MaxAnisotropy = 1;
        samplerDescription.ComparisonFunc = D3D12_COMPARISON_FUNC_ALWAYS;

        CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE samplerHandle(samplerHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart(), samplerIndex, samplerDescriptorSize);
        Renderer::GetInstance()->GetDevice()->CreateSampler(&samplerDescription, samplerHandle);
    }

    String GetName() const
    {
        return name;
    }

    String GetLocalPath() const
    {
        return localPath;
    }

    String GetDomain() const
    {
        return domain;
    }

    UnorderedMap<String, String> GetPaths() const
    {
        return
        {
            { "vertex", vertexPath },
            { "pixel", pixelPath },
            { "compute", computePath },
            { "geometry", geometryPath },
            { "hull", hullPath },
            { "domain", domainPath }
        };
    }

    ComPtr<ID3D12RootSignature> GetRootSignature() const
    {
        return rootSignature;
    }

    ComPtr<ID3D12PipelineState> GetPipelineState() const
    {
        return pipelineState;
    }

    void CleanUp()
    {
        for (auto& buffer : constantBuffers)
        {
            if (buffer)
                buffer->Unmap(0, nullptr);
        }
    }

    static Shared<Shader> Create(const String& name, const String& localPath, Shared<RootSignature> rootSignature, const String& domain = Settings::GetInstance()->Get<String>("defaultDomain"))
    {
        Shared<Shader> out = std::make_shared<Shader>();

        out->name = name;
        out->localPath = localPath;
        out->domain = domain;
        out->vertexPath = "Assets/" + domain + "/" + localPath + "Vertex.hlsl";
        out->pixelPath = "Assets/" + domain + "/" + localPath + "Pixel.hlsl";
        out->computePath = "Assets/" + domain + "/" + localPath + "Compute.hlsl";
        out->geometryPath = "Assets/" + domain + "/" + localPath + "Geometry.hlsl";
        out->hullPath = "Assets/" + domain + "/" + localPath + "Hull.hlsl";
        out->domainPath = "Assets/" + domain + "/" + localPath + "Domain.hlsl";
        out->rootSignature = rootSignature->Generate();

        out->Generate();

        return std::move(out);
    }

private:

    void Generate()
    {
        //Just compiles shaders and creates the pso
    }

    void CreateDescriptorHeaps()
    {
        D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_DESC constantBufferViewShaderResourceViewUnorderedAccessViewHeapDescription = {};

        constantBufferViewShaderResourceViewUnorderedAccessViewHeapDescription.NumDescriptors = maxConstantBuffers + maxTextures;
        constantBufferViewShaderResourceViewUnorderedAccessViewHeapDescription.Type = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV;
        constantBufferViewShaderResourceViewUnorderedAccessViewHeapDescription.Flags = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_SHADER_VISIBLE;

        HRESULT result = Renderer::GetInstance()->GetDevice()->CreateDescriptorHeap(&constantBufferViewShaderResourceViewUnorderedAccessViewHeapDescription, IID_PPV_ARGS(&constantBufferViewShaderResourceViewUnorderedAccessViewHeap));

        if (FAILED(result))
            Logger_ThrowError("D3D12", "Failed to create CBV/SRV/UAV descriptor heap", true);

        constantBufferViewShaderResourceViewUnorderedAccessViewDescriptorSize = Renderer::GetInstance()->GetDevice()->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV);

        D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_DESC samplerHeapDescription = {};

        samplerHeapDescription.NumDescriptors = maxTextures;
        samplerHeapDescription.Type = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_SAMPLER;
        samplerHeapDescription.Flags = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_SHADER_VISIBLE;

        result = Renderer::GetInstance()->GetDevice()->CreateDescriptorHeap(&samplerHeapDescription, IID_PPV_ARGS(&samplerHeap));

        if (FAILED(result))
            Logger_ThrowError("D3D12", "Failed to create sampler descriptor heap", true);

        samplerDescriptorSize = Renderer::GetInstance()->GetDevice()->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_SAMPLER);
    }

    ComPtr<IDxcBlob> CompileShader(ComPtr<IDxcUtils>& utils, ComPtr<IDxcCompiler3>& compiler, ComPtr<IDxcIncludeHandler>& includeHandler, const String& path, const wchar_t* target)
    {
        //Long and compilicated function...
    }

    void CreateGraphicsPipelineState(ComPtr<IDxcBlob>& vertexShaderBlob, ComPtr<IDxcBlob>& pixelShaderBlob, ComPtr<IDxcBlob>& geometryShaderBlob, ComPtr<IDxcBlob>& hullShaderBlob, ComPtr<IDxcBlob>& domainShaderBlob)
    {
        D3D12_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_STATE_DESC pipelineStateDescription = {};

        pipelineStateDescription.VS = vertexShaderBlob ? D3D12_SHADER_BYTECODE{ vertexShaderBlob->GetBufferPointer(), vertexShaderBlob->GetBufferSize() } : D3D12_SHADER_BYTECODE{};
        pipelineStateDescription.PS = pixelShaderBlob ? D3D12_SHADER_BYTECODE{ pixelShaderBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pixelShaderBlob->GetBufferSize() } : D3D12_SHADER_BYTECODE{};
        pipelineStateDescription.GS = geometryShaderBlob ? D3D12_SHADER_BYTECODE{ geometryShaderBlob->GetBufferPointer(), geometryShaderBlob->GetBufferSize() } : D3D12_SHADER_BYTECODE{};
        pipelineStateDescription.HS = hullShaderBlob ? D3D12_SHADER_BYTECODE{ hullShaderBlob->GetBufferPointer(), hullShaderBlob->GetBufferSize() } : D3D12_SHADER_BYTECODE{};
        pipelineStateDescription.DS = domainShaderBlob ? D3D12_SHADER_BYTECODE{ domainShaderBlob->GetBufferPointer(), domainShaderBlob->GetBufferSize() } : D3D12_SHADER_BYTECODE{};

        pipelineStateDescription.pRootSignature = rootSignature.Get();
        pipelineStateDescription.RasterizerState = CD3DX12_RASTERIZER_DESC(D3D12_DEFAULT);
        pipelineStateDescription.BlendState = CD3DX12_BLEND_DESC(D3D12_DEFAULT);
        pipelineStateDescription.DepthStencilState = CD3DX12_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC(D3D12_DEFAULT);
        pipelineStateDescription.InputLayout = { Vertex::GetInputLayout().data(), (uint)Vertex::GetInputLayout().size() };
        pipelineStateDescription.SampleMask = UINT_MAX;
        pipelineStateDescription.PrimitiveTopologyType = D3D12_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TYPE_TRIANGLE;
        pipelineStateDescription.NumRenderTargets = 1;
        pipelineStateDescription.RTVFormats[0] = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
        pipelineStateDescription.DSVFormat = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;
        pipelineStateDescription.SampleDesc.Count = 1;

        HRESULT result = Renderer::GetInstance()->GetDevice()->CreateGraphicsPipelineState(&pipelineStateDescription, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pipelineState));

        if (FAILED(result))
            Logger_ThrowError("FAILED", "Failed to create graphics pipeline state", true);
    }

    //Member variables
};

And finally, the order in which operations are called:
void Render()
{
    if (!shader) //'shader' and 'texture' are both std::shared_ptr
        return;

    texture->Bind();
    shader->Bind();

    UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
    UINT offset = 0;

    ComPtr<ID3D12GraphicsCommandList> commandList = Renderer::GetInstance()->GetCommandList();

    commandList->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vertexBufferView);
    commandList->IASetIndexBuffer(&indexBufferView);
    commandList->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    commandList->DrawIndexedInstanced(static_cast<UINT>(indices.size()), 1, 0, 0, 0);
}

I have tried using ChatGPT, looking at Microsoft Learn, creating a Minimal Reproducible Example, but nothing really worked. I just cannot find the correct way to set a texture!

There's a lot of code but not much else. What exactly happens when you run this code? 'memcpy error' doesn't mean much to me. Where does the error happen? Which line of the code above? Have you tried running the code with a debugger, what did that tell you?

Your Generate function releases the actual image data on completion, so the pointers in D3D12_SUBRESOURCE_DATA subresourceData point to garbage memory.
You have to actually copy the data from imageData into textureUploadHeap BEFORE exiting that function using the D3D12_SUBRESOURCE_DATA subresourceData. The subresourceData is not valid after exiting so it might as well be a local variable as well.
This is where D3DX12 utility code like UpdateSubresources comes in handy since you can't just do a single memcpy since the texture will have an aligned pitch.
You may find it helpful to look at WICTextureLoader and ResourceUploadBatch in the DirectX Tool Kit for DX12.
